Aligment problem after switching from one form 'card' to another
I've created this form page which lets you search and insert elements into a database. It's simple, there are two buttons "ricerca" (search) and 'inserimento'(insert) each one opening a different 'bootstrap card'. Each card contains a form. I can't explain why, when I click on the insert button, all the elements move slightly to the left.
Can you guess why?


<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"
              integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


<style>
  
body {
    text-align: center;
}


.gruppo-2 {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>Benvenuto<br><br></p>


<button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ricerca" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1">Ricerca <i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
<button type='button' class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#inserimento" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1">Inserimento <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button>


<br><br><br>



<div id="myGroup">


<div class="collapse" id="ricerca" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
    <div class="gruppo-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <form method="get" action='DBsearch.php' class = 'card p-3 bg-light'>
            <label class="control-label " for="Postazioni">
            <b>Postazione:</b>
            </label>
            <select class="form-select" id="PostazioniS" name="Postazioni" type='search'>
            <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
            <option value="Tutte">Tutte</option>


            </select>

            <div class="flex-container">

            <label class="control-label" for="Data">
            <p><b>Da:</b></p>
            </label>

            <input class="form-control" id="Data" name="Data" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text"/>

            <label class="control-label" for="DataA">
            <p><b>A:</b></p>
            </label>

            <input class="form-control" id="DataA" name="DataA" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text"/>


            <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
                <b>Cerca</b>
            </button>
            </div>

            </form>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="collapse" id="inserimento" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
      <div class="gruppo-2">
          <form method="get" action='DBinsert.php'>
            <div class="card p-3 bg-light">
              <div class="card-body">
              <div class= 'row g-3'>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label " for="Postazioni">
                <b>Postazione:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="Postazioni" name="Postazioni" type='number' required>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="Data2">
                <b>Data:</b>
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="Data2" name="Data2" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="Ora">
                <b>Ora:</b>
                </label>
                <input class= "form-control" type="time" id="Ora" name="Ora" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <label class="control-label " for="Verbale">
                <b>Tipo di verbale:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="Verbale" name="Verbale" type='text' required>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                </select>
                </div>


                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="NSet">
                <b>Set:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="NSet" name="NSet" type='number' required>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="Flash">
                <b>Flash:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="Flash" name="Flash" type='number' required>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Protocollo:</b></label> 
                <input id="Protocollo" name="Protocollo" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Scatti da:</b></label> 
                <input id="ScattiDa" name="ScattiDa" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>a:</b></label> 
                <input id="ScattiA" name="ScattiA" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="card p-3 bg-warning mb-3" id='notShown' style='display: none;'>
            <h5>SCARICO DATI</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
              <div class= 'row g-3'>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="DataCartelleDa">
                <b>Data cartelle da:</b>
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="DataCartelleDa" name="DataCartelleDa" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="DataCartelleA">
                <b>Data cartelle a:</b>
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="DataCartelleA" name="DataCartelleA" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Numero Cartelle:</b></label> 
                <input id="NumeroCartelle" name="NumeroCartelle" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="DataScarico">
                <b>Data Scarico:</b>
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" id="DataScarico" name="DataScarico" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label" for="OraScarico">
                <b>Ora Scarico:</b>
                </label>
                <input class= "form-control" type="time" id="OraScarico" name="OraScarico" required/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="card p-3 bg-light">
          <h5>VERBALIZZANTI E NOTE</h5>
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class= 'row g-3'>
                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="Agente 1">
                <b>Agente 1:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="Agente1" name="Agente1" type='number' required>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                <label class="control-label " for="Agente 2">
                <b>Agente 2:</b>
                </label>
                <select class="form-select" id="Agente2" name="Agente2" type='number' required>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Note:</b></label> 
                <input id="Note" name="Note" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" type="submit">
                Inserisci
                </button>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>

              </div>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>



By deleting some of the elements in the 'inserimento' card, the problem is solved, and the two cards remain alignet to the center.
I can't explain why.

Is it possible that you removed the widest element?

Please convert your example into a snippet.

I added a snippet

The 'inserimento' card is too tall and causes vertical overflow, showing vertical scroll bar. That's why when you delete some elements in that card, the problem seem to be "solved". You can try fixing this without deleting card content by adding overflow-y: scroll; to body. This make the vertical scroll bar to always be shown, ugly, I know, but it won't push things around anymore.


<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js" integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Date-Picker Plugin -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.it.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
            
    .gruppo-2 {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Benvenuto<br><br></p>


  <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#ricerca" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1">Ricerca <i class="bi bi-search"></i></button>
  <button type='button' class="btn btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#inserimento" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-b1">Inserimento <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></button>


  <br><br><br>



  <div id="myGroup">


    <div class="collapse" id="ricerca" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
      <div class="gruppo-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <form method="get" action='DBsearch.php' class='card p-3 bg-light'>
              <label class="control-label " for="Postazioni">
            <b>Postazione:</b>
            </label>
              <select class="form-select" id="PostazioniS" name="Postazioni" type='search'>
                <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                <option value="Tutte">Tutte</option>


              </select>

              <div class="flex-container">

                <label class="control-label" for="Data">
            <p><b>Da:</b></p>
            </label>

                <input class="form-control" id="Data" name="Data" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" />

                <label class="control-label" for="DataA">
            <p><b>A:</b></p>
            </label>

                <input class="form-control" id="DataA" name="DataA" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" />


                <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">
                <b>Cerca</b>
            </button>
              </div>

            </form>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <div class="collapse" id="inserimento" data-bs-parent="#myGroup">
      <div class="gruppo-2">
        <form method="get" action='DBinsert.php'>
          <div class="card p-3 bg-light">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class='row g-3'>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Postazioni">
                <b>Postazione:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="Postazioni" name="Postazioni" type='number' required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Data2">
                <b>Data:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="Data2" name="Data2" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label" for="Ora">
                <b>Ora:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="time" id="Ora" name="Ora" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Verbale">
                <b>Tipo di verbale:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="Verbale" name="Verbale" type='text' required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>


                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="NSet">
                <b>Set:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="NSet" name="NSet" type='number' required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Flash">
                <b>Flash:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="Flash" name="Flash" type='number' required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Protocollo:</b></label>
                  <input id="Protocollo" name="Protocollo" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Scatti da:</b></label>
                  <input id="ScattiDa" name="ScattiDa" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>a:</b></label>
                  <input id="ScattiA" name="ScattiA" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="card p-3 bg-warning mb-3" id='notShown' style='display: none;'>
            <h5>SCARICO DATI</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class='row g-3'>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="DataCartelleDa">
                <b>Data cartelle da:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="DataCartelleDa" name="DataCartelleDa" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="DataCartelleA">
                <b>Data cartelle a:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="DataCartelleA" name="DataCartelleA" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                  <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Numero Cartelle:</b></label>
                  <input id="NumeroCartelle" name="NumeroCartelle" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="DataScarico">
                <b>Data Scarico:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="DataScarico" name="DataScarico" placeholder="AAAA/MM/GG" type="text" required/>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label" for="OraScarico">
                <b>Ora Scarico:</b>
                </label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="time" id="OraScarico" name="OraScarico" required/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="card p-3 bg-light">
            <h5>VERBALIZZANTI E NOTE</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class='row g-3'>
                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Agente 1">
                <b>Agente 1:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="Agente1" name="Agente1" type='number' required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected selected hidden>Seleziona...</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                  <label class="control-label " for="Agente 2">
                <b>Agente 2:</b>
                </label>
                  <select class="form-select" id="Agente2" name="Agente2" type='number' required>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="text" class="col-4 col-form-label"><b>Note:</b></label>
                  <input id="Note" name="Note" type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="col-12">
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" type="submit">
                Inserisci
                </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>




That's wonderful, thank you very much
